# Eclipse arrow keys not working once I launch an android app in the emulator. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, editor

I am learning to use Eclipse to develop Android apps. Once I have launched my app in the android emulator (using the run button in Eclipse) I cant seem to edit any of my source files anymore. Neither do the arrow keys work in source files.

Why is this and how can I get the arrow keys and editing to work?

I suspected that this might be because the app is running. However this behavior persists even after I kill the app running in the emulator using DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this happening to me at some stage but I can't for the life of me remember what it was!!  Is there an eclipse dialog that is being shown somewhere?  Try minimising eclipse or looking for a dialog appearing when you're running your app.  Alternatively, try updating the android plugins to a later version in case it's a bug that they've fixed.